# how to retrieve java map in javascript?

Tags: jsf-1.2

I'm using JSF1.2 apache trinidad tag. I have a requirement like based on the drop down list the associated list of array values should get rendered into the UI.My Bean will have a map (drop down value as key which is unique, the associated list of values retrieved from DB) will be readily available when the page loads. In java script, how to retrieve the associated list value from this map and how to return back the array value into UI? Is there any other options available to achieve this requirement?

Your help on this is really much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you have the entire map available when the page is rendered.
You could prebuild the selectItems in the dropdown beforehand like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;
//read the map content here
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for(String key: map.keySet()){
    items.add(new SelectItem(key, map.get(key)));
}
```

These items will have the key as the label and the corresponding array as the value.
When you use this in your interface you can do this:

```
<tr:selectOneChoice value="#{bean.selectedArray}" required="true" autoSubmit="true">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}"
</tr:selectOneChoice>
<tr:outputText value="#{bean.selectedArray}" />
```

The code isn't complete, but it should get you started.